# "import datetime" v.s. "from datetime import datetime"

Tags: python, datetime, attributeerror

I have a script that needs to execute the following at different lines in the script:

```
today_date = datetime.date.today()
date_time = datetime.strp(date_time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

In my `import` statements I have the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strp'
```

If I change the order of the `import` statements to:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'
```

If I again change the `import` statement to:

```
import datetime
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strp'
```

What is going on here and how do I get both to work?

Comment: There is *no* `strp` method on `datetime.datetime` *either*, you probably meant `datetime.datetime.strptime()` instead.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Your trouble is that you have some code that is expecting `datetime` to be a reference to the `datetime` *module* and other code that is expecting `datetime` to be a reference to the `datetime` *class.* Obviously, it can't be both.

When you do:

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
```

You are first setting `datetime` to be a reference to the class, then immediately setting it to be a reference to the module. When you do it the other way around, it instead ends up being a reference to the class. Last assignment "wins."

You need to rename one of these references.  For example:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
```

Then you can change references in the form `datetime.xxxx` that refer to the module to `dt.xxxx`.

Or else just `import datetime` and change all references to use the module name.  In other words, if something just says `datetime(...)` you need to change that reference to `datetime.datetime`.

Python has a fair bit of this kind of thing in its library, unfortunately. If they followed their own naming guidelines in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the `datetime` class would be named `Datetime` and there'd be no problem using both `datetime` to mean the module and `Datetime` to mean the class.

Comment: renaming the module doesn't seem like a good option. Either use `import datetime` or `from datetime import datetime`, not both.

Comment: I think the best is to just do import datetime, and then when using the class, do datetime.datetime.  This way the code is clear and less prone to errors.  It's annoying to carry datetime.datetime throughout all the code but the poor naming of this library leaves no option for the sake of clarity IMO.

Comment: can you do something ike `import datetime as Datetime`?

Comment: Per @kindall suggestion of PEP 8, then I propose the following `from datetime import datetime as DateTime, timedelta as TimeDelta, date as Date`

Comment: `from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta` etc and any other classes you require that would come from `import datetime`

Comment: @jfs, why is renaming a bad option, given widespread renaming of other modules: `import pandas as pd`, `import numpy as np` etc

Comment: @alancalvitti the less context you need to understand the code the better. Though over the years, I've moved to `import datetime as DT` (the general preference to import modules—especially for 3rd party names): `now = DT.datetime.now(DT.timezone.utc)` (`dt` lowercase is still reserved for local names for datetime objects)

Comment: @jfs, I disagree, after all, calling any function requires more context compared to writing code inline. - What's really needed - at least in Jupiter - is a mouseover that shows what DT means. - Btw do you suggest `import pandas as PD` to save `pd` for local vars? - good idea but again, that's now what's out in the wild.

Comment: @alancalvitti wrong. More code does not make it more readable necessarily (e.g. if you were to replace a single 200-line function with 200 calls to other custom functions for each line, how do you think it would affect readability? (I bet, it would make it worse). 2- `pd` & `np` for `pandas` & `numpy` are common and it is unlikely that you would confuse them with local names (it is ok to use them).

Comment: @jfs, what is wrong? I'm arguing the same thing - maybe I made it too terse to follow. The analogy is: `def f()...` is to `import datetime as dt`. Then elsewhere reference to `f` and `dt` only, not the body of the function and not `datetime` (module). In both cases, there are typically multiple references and both cases add context.

Answer (score 36):

You cannot use both statements; the `datetime` **module** contains a `datetime` **type**. The local name `datetime` in your own module can only refer to one or the other.

Use *only* `import datetime`, then make sure that you always use `datetime.datetime` to refer to the contained type:

```
import datetime

today_date = datetime.date.today()
date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Now `datetime` is the module, and you refer to the contained types via that.

Alternatively, import *all* types you need from the module:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

today_date = date.today()
date_time = datetime.strptime(date_time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Here `datetime` is the type from the module. `date` is another type, from the same module.

Comment: Thank you very much Martijn. It is confusing why they named a type with the same name as the module. I'm a newbie with python and developing in general so maybe this is some sort of best practice. In any case thank you kindly.

Comment: @codingknob it's not, they messed up with this. The official python style guide (PEP8) explicitly says to name things differently, but I guess this code is from before the publication of the style guide..

Comment: @Fabiano the style guide also has things to say about flexibility and consistency within a codebase. The types were lowercased because other Python standard types are lowercased. `list`, `dict`, `set`, `str`, `int`, `float`, `tuple`, `bool`, so `datetime`, `date`, `timedelta` naturally follow.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sure, but then why is `from decimal import Decimal`? `Decimal` is also a type.. What I meant to say is that things changed along the way, I think on the first python versions, type was different than a class, you couldn't subclass `dict` for example, and today you can. My point though was to stress that the way `datetime` is named is *not* a "some sort of best practice" as @codingknob said.

Comment: @Fabiano the thing is: `datetime` was developed by Tim Peters who saw it as part of the core builtins [in the early 2000s](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2a799bf77a83adef010ff4751e5195702f159f39) (while he and I both worked at Zope Corp). PEP 8 was [already published and established](https://github.com/python/peps/blob/8e4c8019b1e4afd1f7d4565ed9aae830d2f57385/pep-0008.txt), almost 18 months old by then. I know Tim’s reasoning because I remember some of the discussions.

Comment: @Fabiano: Decimal on the other hand started earlier, as an [external project named FixedPoint, also by Tim](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-February/thread.html#32950). The difference being that it was an external project to start with.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Very interesting, thanks for the history and background, I see his reasoning, the name would definitely have worked better if it was indeed a builtin instead of an stdlib module, avoiding the name clash. Anyhow, in the grand scheme of things, it is a very very small quirk, the way I see Python is still one of the most beautifully and carefully designed languages out there. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`datetime` is a module which contains a type that is also called `datetime`.  You appear to want to use both, but you're trying to use the same name to refer to both.  The type and the module are two different things and you can't refer to both of them with the name `datetime` in your program.

If you need to use anything from the module besides the `datetime` type (as you apparently do), then you need to import the module with `import datetime`.  You can then refer to the "date" type as `datetime.date` and the datetime type as `datetime.datetime`.

You could also do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
today_date = date.today()
date_time = datetime.strp(date_time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Here you import only the names you need (the datetime and date types) and import them directly so you don't need to refer to the module itself at all.

Ultimately you have to decide what names from the module you need to use, and how best to use them.  If you are only using one or two things from the module (e.g., just the `date` and `datetime` types), it may be okay to import those names directly.  If you're using many things, it's probably better to import the module and access the things inside it using dot syntax, to avoid cluttering your global namespace with date-specific names.

Note also that, if you do import the module name itself, you can shorten the name to ease typing:

```
import datetime as dt
today_date = dt.date.today()
date_time = dt.datetime.strp(date_time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: But also bearing in mind, that if you don't use the actual module, then using `import datetime as dt` does *not* shorten your typing as much as `from datetime import datetime`, because then instead of having to type `dt.datetime` everywhere, you can just type `datetime`, and also no-one is reading your code wondering "what the heck is 'dt'?".

Answer (score 2):

The difference between from datetime import datetime and normal import datetime is that , you are dealing with a module at one time and a class at other.

The strptime function only exists in the datetime class so you have to import the class with the module otherwise you have to specify datetime twice when calling this function.

The thing here is that , the class name and the module name has been given the same name so it creates a bit of confusuion.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt

today_date = datetime.date.today()
date_time = dt.strptime(date_time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

strp() doesn't exist. I think you mean strptime.

Comment: Is this any different to just doing `dt = datetime.datetime`?

Comment: @Eric: No, it has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
today=datetime.today()
print("Todays Date:",today)
yesterday=today-datetime,timedelta(days=1)
print("Yesterday date:",yesterday)
tommorrow=today+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print("Tommorrow Date:",tommorrow)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22051839)