# Csv editing of files by each field

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am new to python and my teacher has told me to create a code that can edit a csv file by each field depending on the value in it.
Here is a nested list to show the csv file which is split into lists by lines then by elements:

```
[["A","B","C","D"],["Yes",1,"05/11/2016","0"],["No","12","05/06/2017","1"],["Yes","6","08/09/2017","2"]]
```

What I am supposed to do is to make a loop which can be used to detect the postions of the elements within the inner list and then change the first element of each list to a "No" if it is a yes ,the 3rd element to today's date if the date stated is at least 6 months back and the last element to a 1 if it is more than 1 ,how am I supposed to do this?

Below is my code:

```
filename="Assignment_Data1.csv"
file=open(filepath+filename,"r")
reader=csv.reader(file,delimiter=",")
from datetime import datetime
six_months = str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(6*365/12-1))
fm_six_months=str(datetime.datetime.strptime(six_months, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))

td=datetime.now()
deDate = str(td)[8:10] + "/"+ str(td)[5:7] + "/"+ str(td)[0:4]
import csv 
for row in reader:
    for field in row:
        if row[2]<=fm_six_months or row[4]>50 or row[2]<10:
            row[3]=deDate
            row[4]=0
            row[2]=100
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to replace the fields that have the above stated conditions with want I want through a loop ,is it possible?

Comment: Why are you asking if it will work? Have you *tested* it?

Comment: Yes I have tested.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but your code has a couple issues:

1) **Import statements.**

- Your import statements should be all at the top of your program. Currently, you use `csv.reader` in line 3, but haven't imported `csv` yet.
- The way you're importing of the `datetime` module is inconsistent with most of the code. This is somewhat confusing, since [the `datetime` module also has a `datetime` *class*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707532/python-import-datetime-v-s-from-datetime-import-datetime). Given what you want to do, it would be easiest to change the import statement to `import datetime` and change line 8 to `td=datetime.datetime.now()` (`now` is a function of the datetime class).

2) **Iterating over `field` *and* `row` is redundant.** The construct you have, `for row in reader: for field in row`, will run your `if` statements additional times that are unnecessary.

3) **Python is zero-indexed.** This means that the first element is a list is accessed using `row[0]`, not `row[1]`. In your case, the fourth column of your CSV would be accessed with `row[3]`.

4) **You're combining conditions.** From the phrasing of the assignment, it sounds like each of the conditions (like "change the first element to a No if it is a yes") is supposed to be independent of the other. However, `if row[2]<=fm_six_months or row[4]>50 or row[2]<10` means that you'll change the data if *any* condition is true. It sounds like you need three separate `if` blocks.

5) **Your code has no writer.** This is really the big one. Simply saying `row[2] = 100` doesn't do anything lasting, as `row` is just an object in memory; changing `row` doesn't actually change the CSV file on your computer. To actually modify the csv, you'll need to write it back out to file, using a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Comment: ermm how would I be able to do this ?

Comment: I dont undestand how to do the writer

Comment: @nTIAO you need to put a little more effort into reading the answer, researching and testing. You can't expect every one to cater to your needs.

Comment: i did do research but  my code is still not working should I upoload it here?

Comment: @nTIAO, yes, you should definitely edit your question with your most recent code. However, I'll also add that a good example of the CSV reader is on the page that I linked.