# Subtracting pandas Dataframe values from today's date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name  A    B    C
D1    1    3    3
D2    2    4    4
D3    2    1    1
```

How can I create a new dataframe of the same size where every value is today's date minus the value of my first dataframe?

for example, if today is 2018-04-27, my new dataframe would look like this:

```
Name  A             B             C  
D1    2018-04-26    2018-04-24    2018-04-24
D2    2018-04-25    2018-04-23    2018-04-23
D3    2018-04-25    2018-04-26    2018-04-26
```

I'm thinking the solution will include something like

```
df2.iloc[1,1] = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=df1[1,1])
```

but I'm running into all kinds of type errors and problems looping through the original df

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['D1','D2','D3'],'A':[1,2,2],'B':[3,4,1],'C':[3,4,1]})
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: dt.date.today() - timedelta(days = x))

df2 
                   A           B           C
    Name
    D1    2018-04-26  2018-04-24  2018-04-24
    D2    2018-04-25  2018-04-23  2018-04-23
    D3    2018-04-25  2018-04-26  2018-04-26
```

[Applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is what you're looking to use

Edit: adding imports so that you avoid issues with datetime imports as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707532/python-import-datetime-v-s-from-datetime-import-datetime)

Comment: Nice! If you want to avoid importing `datetime`, you can also use this lambda: `lambda x: pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_timedelta(str(x)+'d'))`

Comment: @sacul it is better do not using applymap , I am worry about the speed :-(

Answer (score 1):

It is better do not using `applymap`

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

pd.to_datetime('today').date()-df.apply(pd.to_timedelta,unit='d')
Out[428]: 
               A           B           C
Name                                    
D1    2018-04-26  2018-04-24  2018-04-24
D2    2018-04-25  2018-04-23  2018-04-23
D3    2018-04-25  2018-04-26  2018-04-26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the DataFrame's values so that you can pass them to `pd.to_timedelta()`.  This saves you from needing to use either `.applymap()` or `.apply()`:

```
today = pd.to_datetime(dt.date(2018, 4, 27))
deltas = pd.to_timedelta(df.values.flatten(), unit='d')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape((today - deltas).values, df2.shape),
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Result:

```
>>> df2
              A          B          C
Name                                 
D1   2018-04-26 2018-04-24 2018-04-24
D2   2018-04-25 2018-04-23 2018-04-23
D3   2018-04-25 2018-04-26 2018-04-26

>>> df2.dtypes
A    datetime64[ns]
B    datetime64[ns]
C    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```