# import datetime - Clarification

Tags: python, django

''''

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now().time()
print(now)

o/p: 21:44:22.612870
```

''''
But, when i am trying:
''''

```
import datetime
now = datetime.now().time()
print(now)
```

''''

it give following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/3. WorkSpace/3. Django/datemodel/first.py", line 9, in 
    now = datetime.now().time() # time object
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

> > > any one explain what is difference between both?

Comment: [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=replace#available-types) contains different types, `date`, `time` and `datetime` amongst others. The module name is the same as one of the types it defines, hence `from datetime import datetime` and `import datetime` are not importing the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["import datetime" v.s. "from datetime import datetime"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707532/import-datetime-v-s-from-datetime-import-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datetime library exports a module called datetime.

Modules are Python .py files that consist of Python code. Any Python file can be referenced as a module.

if you want you can also use it this way:

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```