# from datetime import datetime VS import datetime

Tags: python, datetime, import, python-3.7

What is the difference between: `from datetime import datetime` and `import datetime`

I often just do `from datetime import datetime`, but what is the difference, and why do some people use one over the other?

Language:Python3.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python "import datetime" v.s. "from datetime import datetime"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707532/python-import-datetime-v-s-from-datetime-import-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `import datetime`, you're importing the datetime module, which contains the datetime class. When you use `from datetime import datetime`, you're importing just the datetime class from the datetime module. So, if you're only using the datetime class from the datetime module, then `from datetime import datetime` is fine. Otherwise, if you use `import datetime`, you'll have to use `datetime.datetime` to access the datetime class.